# Assembly language error in output

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm learning assembly and I wrote a simple program to write strings to the screen as goes:

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp

mov bx, HELLO_MSG
call print_string

mov bx, GOODBYE_MSG
call print_string

jmp $

print_string:
    pusha

    mov ah, 0x0e

    for_block:
        mov al, [bx]
        int 0x10
        add bx, 0x1

    cmp bl, 0
    jne for_block

    popa
    ret

HELLO_MSG:
    db "Hello, World", 0

GOODBYE_MSG:
    db "Goodbye", 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

But the output is "Hello World Goodbye" then a bunch of space then another "Goodbye", more space and it ends in the middle of nowhere some lines below.

I'm emulating in Bochs.

Comment: Which assembly are you using?

Comment: You're doing `cmp bl, 0`. But `bl` will never be zero since it's the index. You want `cmp [bx],0`.

Comment: `cmp bl, 0` should be `cmp byte [bx], 0`

Comment: You should also not use `bx` as counter, because it's also an input argument to `int 10h Ah=0Eh`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was cmp bx, 0. Because we were moving across the string with al the cmp should be done on it to get the stopping point.

Answer (score 0):

Compare each letter with zero after loading it:
Also, use SI as a pointer instead of BX, because BX is an input for the BIOS function you use.

```
[org 0x7c00]

mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp

mov si, HELLO_MSG
push cs
pop ds

call print_string

mov si, GOODBYE_MSG
push cs
pop ds
call print_string

jmp $

print_string:
    pusha

    mov ah, 0x0e

    for_block:
        lodsb ;loading the byte on the offset specified in SI. SI is automatically incremented here.
    cmp al, 0
    je exit
        int 0x10
        add bx, 0x1
    jmp for_block

exit:
    popa
    ret

HELLO_MSG:
    db "Hello, World", 0

GOODBYE_MSG:
    db "Goodbye", 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```